# Chaotic geo image in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am working with `qmap` (R package [ggmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html)) and when I enter the following code:

```
qmap("Rotterdam", maptype = "terrain", zoom = 13) +
geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = pOpleidingHigh), 
             data = dfDataPlus,
             colour = "white", 
             alpha = 0.8, size = 0.5)
```

I get the following output:

[image: Picture 1]

As you can see the picture is very chaotic and unclear, because of the multiple squares.

Below an example of my data:

```
    > dput(dfDataPlus[1:5,1:29])
```

`structure(list(id = c("2651", "2651", "2651", "2651", "2651"), 
    long = c(4.49239869, 4.49238217, 4.47727316, 4.48418196, 
    4.49243175), lat = c(51.99922025, 51.99921236, 51.98782511, 
    51.99653866, 51.99923602), order = c(235L, 236L, 398L, 282L, 
    234L), hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), piece = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
    "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2651.1", "2651.2", "2651.3", 
    "2651.4", "2651.5", "2651.6", "2651.7", "2651.8", "2652.1", 
    "2652.2", "2652.3", "2652.4", "2652.5", "2652.6", "2652.7", 
    "2652.8", "2652.9", "2661.1", "2661.2", "2662.1", "2662.2", 
    "2665.1", "2671.1", "2671.2", "2671.3", "2671.4", "2671.5", 
    "2671.6", "2671.7", "2671.8", "2671.9", "2671.10", "2672.1", 
    "2672.2", "2672.3", "2672.4", "2672.5", "2672.6", "2673.1", 
    "2673.2", "2673.3", "2673.4", "2675.1", "2676.1", "2678.1", 
    "2681.1", "2681.2", "2684.1", "2685.1", "2685.2", "2691.1", 
    "2691.2", "2691.3", "2691.4", "2691.5", "2691.6", "2691.7", 
    "2691.8", "2691.9", "2692.1", "2693.1", "2693.2", "2693.3", 
    "2694.1", "2694.2", "2694.3", "2694.4", "2711.1", "2711.2", 
    "2711.3", "2711.4", "2711.5", "2711.6", "2712.1", "2712.2", 
    "2712.3", "2712.4", "2712.5", "2712.6", "2712.7", "2712.8", 
    "2712.9", "2712.10", "2712.11", "2713.1", "2713.2", "2713.3", 
    "2713.4", "2713.5", "2715.1", "2715.2", "2716.1", "2717.1", 
    "2718.1", "2718.2", "2718.3", "2718.4", "2718.5", "2719.1", 
    "2719.2", "2719.3", "2719.4", "2721.1", "2722.1", "2722.2", 
    "2722.3", "2722.4", "2722.5", "2723.1", "2723.2", "2724.1", 
    "2724.2", "2725.1", "2725.2", "2726.1", "2727.1", "2727.2", 
    "2728.1", "2729.1", "2729.2", "2731.1", "2735.1", "2741.1", 
    "2741.2", "2741.3", "2742.1", "2742.2", "2742.3", "2743.1", 
    "2743.2", "2751.1", "2752.1", "2761.1", "2761.2", "2771.1", 
    "2801.1", "2802.1", "2803.1", "2803.2", "2804.1", "2805.1", 
    "2806.1", "2806.2", "2806.3", "2807.1", "2808.1", "2809.1", 
    "2811.1", "2821.1", "2825.1", "2831.1", "2840.1", "2841.1", 
    "2841.2", "2851.1", "2855.1", "2861.1", "2865.1", "2871.1", 
    "2871.2", "2872.1", "2872.2", "2901.1", "2902.1", "2902.2", 
    "2903.1", "2904.1", "2905.1", "2906.1", "2907.1", "2908.1", 
    "2909.1", "2911.1", "2912.1", "2913.1", "2913.2", "2913.3", 
    "2914.1", "2914.2", "2921.1", "2921.2", "2922.1", "2922.2", 
    "2923.1", "2924.1", "2924.2", "2924.3", "2925.1", "2925.2", 
    "2926.1", "2931.1", "2935.1", "2941.1", "2951.1", "2951.2", 
    "2952.1", "2952.2", "2953.1", "2954.1", "2954.2", "2957.1", 
    "2957.2", "2959.1", "2961.1", "2964.1", "2964.2", "2965.1", 
    "2967.1", "2967.2", "2968.1", "2969.1", "2971.1", "2973.1", 
    "2974.1", "2974.2", "2974.3", "2975.1", "2975.2", "2975.3", 
    "2977.1", "2981.1", "2981.2", "2981.3", "2982.1", "2983.1", 
    "2984.1", "2985.1", "2985.2", "2986.1", "2986.2", "2987.1", 
    "2987.2", "2988.1", "2989.1", "2991.1", "2991.2", "2992.1", 
    "2992.2", "2992.3", "2993.1", "2993.2", "2994.1", "2995.1", 
    "2995.2", "2995.3", "3011.1", "3012.1", "3013.1", "3013.2", 
    "3014.1", "3015.1", "3015.2", "3016.1", "3021.1", "3021.2", 
    "3022.1", "3023.1", "3024.1", "3025.1", "3026.1", "3027.1", 
    "3028.1", "3029.1", "3031.1", "3032.1", "3033.1", "3034.1", 
    "3035.1", "3035.2", "3036.1", "3037.1", "3037.2", "3038.1", 
    "3038.2", "3038.3", "3039.1", "3041.1", "3042.1", "3042.2", 
    "3043.1", "3043.2", "3043.3", "3044.1", "3044.2", "3045.1", 
    "3045.2", "3045.3", "3046.1", "3047.1", "3047.2", "3051.1", 
    "3052.1", "3053.1", "3054.1", "3055.1", "3056.1", "3059.1", 
    "3059.2", "3061.1", "3062.1", "3063.1", "3064.1", "3065.1", 
    "3066.1", "3067.1", "3068.1", "3068.2", "3068.3", "3069.1", 
    "3069.2", "3071.1", "3072.1", "3072.2", "3073.1", "3074.1", 
    "3074.2", "3074.3", "3075.1", "3075.2", "3076.1", "3077.1", 
    "3078.1", "3078.2", "3078.3", "3079.1", "3081.1", "3082.1", 
    "3082.2", "3083.1", "3084.1", "3084.2", "3084.3", "3084.4", 
    "3084.5", "3085.1", "3085.2", "3085.3", "3086.1", "3087.1", 
    "3088.1", "3088.2", "3089.1", "3089.2", "3089.3", "3111.1", 
    "3111.2", "3112.1", "3112.2", "3113.1", "3114.1", "3115.1", 
    "3116.1", "3117.1", "3117.2", "3118.1", "3118.2", "3119.1", 
    "3119.2", "3121.1", "3122.1", "3123.1", "3124.1", "3125.1", 
    "3125.2", "3131.1", "3132.1", "3132.2", "3133.1", "3133.2", 
    "3133.3", "3134.1", "3135.1", "3136.1", "3136.2", "3137.1", 
    "3137.2", "3138.1", "3141.1", "3142.1", "3143.1", "3144.1", 
    "3145.1", "3146.1", "3147.1", "3151.1", "3155.1", "3161.1", 
    "3161.2", "3161.3", "3161.4", "3162.1", "3165.1", "3171.1", 
    "3172.1", "3172.2", "3176.1", "3181.1", "3191.1", "3192.1", 
    "3193.1", "3194.1", "3195.1", "3196.1", "3196.2", "3197.1", 
    "3198.1", "3198.2", "3199.1", "3201.1", "3202.1", "3203.1", 
    "3204.1", "3205.1", "3206.1", "3206.2", "3207.1", "3208.1", 
    "3209.1", "3211.1", "3211.2", "3212.1", "3214.1", "3216.1", 
    "3218.1", "3221.1", "3221.2", "3221.3", "3221.4", "3221.5", 
    "3221.6", "3222.1", "3222.2", "3222.3", "3222.4", "3222.5", 
    "3222.6", "3222.7", "3223.1", "3223.2", "3223.3", "3223.4", 
    "3223.5", "3223.6", "3223.7", "3223.8", "3223.9", "3224.1", 
    "3224.2", "3224.3", "3225.1", "3225.2", "3225.3", "3225.4", 
    "3227.1", "3231.1", "3231.2", "3232.1", "3232.2", "3233.1", 
    "3233.2", "3234.1", "3235.1", "3237.1", "3237.2", "3237.3", 
    "3237.4", "3238.1", "3238.2", "3241.1", "3243.1", "3244.1", 
    "3245.1", "3247.1", "3248.1", "3249.1", "3251.1", "3252.1", 
    "3253.1", "3255.1", "3256.1", "3256.2", "3257.1", "3257.2", 
    "3258.1", "3258.2", "3258.3", "3258.4", "3258.5", "3261.1", 
    "3261.2", "3262.1", "3262.2", "3263.1", "3264.1", "3264.2", 
    "3265.1", "3265.2", "3267.1", "3271.1", "3273.1", "3274.1", 
    "3281.1", "3284.1", "3286.1", "3291.1", "3292.1", "3293.1", 
    "3295.1", "3297.1", "3299.1", "3311.1", "3312.1", "3312.2", 
    "3313.1", "3314.1", "3315.1", "3315.2", "3316.1", "3317.1", 
    "3317.2", "3317.3", "3317.4", "3318.1", "3318.2", "3319.1", 
    "3319.2", "3319.3", "3319.4", "3328.1", "3328.2", "3329.1", 
    "3329.2", "3329.3", "3331.1", "3332.1", "3332.2", "3332.3", 
    "3332.4", "3333.1", "3333.2", "3333.3", "3334.1", "3334.2", 
    "3335.1", "3336.1", "3336.2", "3336.3", "3336.4", "3336.5", 
    "3341.1", "3342.1", "3342.2", "3342.3", "3342.4", "3343.1", 
    "3343.2", "3343.3", "3343.4", "3343.5", "3343.6", "3343.7", 
    "3344.1", "3344.2", "3344.3"), class = "factor"), X = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), sumOpleidinghigh = c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L), sumOpleidinglow = c(27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L), sumBeperking = c(46L, 
    46L, 46L, 46L, 46L), sumOuderPersoon = c(152L, 152L, 152L, 
    152L, 152L), sumHerkomst = c(41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L), sumMoeiteRondk = c(43L, 
    43L, 43L, 43L, 43L), sumSoc = c(134L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 134L
    ), statusscore14 = c(1.01434966593117, 1.01434966593117, 
    1.01434966593117, 1.01434966593117, 1.01434966593117), meanBMI = c(24.3171488857854, 
    24.3171488857854, 24.3171488857854, 24.3171488857854, 24.3171488857854
    ), meanAlcoholc = c(26.6535087719298, 26.6535087719298, 26.6535087719298, 
    26.6535087719298, 26.6535087719298), meanGroente = c(841.908270676692, 
    841.908270676692, 841.908270676692, 841.908270676692, 841.908270676692
    ), meanWandelen = c(106.736842105263, 106.736842105263, 106.736842105263, 
    106.736842105263, 106.736842105263), meanSport = c(187.266666666667, 
    187.266666666667, 187.266666666667, 187.266666666667, 187.266666666667
    ), sum_agegrp_1 = c(136L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 136L), sum_agegrp_2 = c(40L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), sum_agegrp_3 = c(55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 
    55L), sum_agegrp_4 = c(109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L), sum_agegrp_5 = c(55L, 
    55L, 55L, 55L, 55L), sum_agegrp_6 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    n = c(17920L, 17920L, 17920L, 17920L, 17920L), pOpleidingHigh = c(0.24812030075188, 
    0.24812030075188, 0.24812030075188, 0.24812030075188, 0.24812030075188
    )), .Names = c("id", "long", "lat", "order", "hole", "piece", 
"group", "X", "sumOpleidinghigh", "sumOpleidinglow", "sumBeperking", 
"sumOuderPersoon", "sumHerkomst", "sumMoeiteRondk", "sumSoc", 
"statusscore14", "meanBMI", "meanAlcoholc", "meanGroente", "meanWandelen", 
"meanSport", "sum_agegrp_1", "sum_agegrp_2", "sum_agegrp_3", 
"sum_agegrp_4", "sum_agegrp_5", "sum_agegrp_6", "n", "pOpleidingHigh"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")`

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data set (using `dput()`)?

Comment: I reckon you have mixed object with piece for group

Comment: I have added a sample of the data with dput, never used it before so please let me if something should be different.

Comment: This represents just one polygon, please provide a larger sample (maybe on pastebin.com with a link in the question, or somewhere else ...)

Comment: Yes, I added the first 100 rows on pastebin via this link: http://pastebin.com/p1r5Wu1R
(I wanted to do the do multiple postal codes, however the second started at 2000 so it was not possible to place that on pastebin.com, hope this is okay as well?)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution a couple of seconds ago, it had to do with the column `order`.I changed the numbers into a decreasing sequence (first these were completely mixed). Now I get the correct output.